# Spock data driven testing with classes to test for "instanceof" assertions

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I have a test where I want to test a specific result to be of a kind of a class.
Asserting this with the *instanceof* keyword. Sadly I did not figured out how to actually provide a data value **expectedClass** in the data table without having a Problem to actually call it with *instanceof*. I think the keyword *instanceof* is the issue here because it only accepts class/interface names. Any idea how I can test what I want to test in another way?

```
class BattleResolverFactoryTest extends Specification {

    def uut = new BattleResolverFactory()

    @Unroll
    def "should return proper BattleResolver for given ConflictType"(Conflict.ConflictType conflictType, Class<? extends BattleResolver> expectedInstance) {
        when:
        def battleResolver = BattleResolverFactory.getResolver(conflictType)
        then:
        battleResolver instanceof expectedClass
        where:
        conflictType                            | expectedClass
        Conflict.ConflictType.INFANTRY_CONFLICT | TestInfantryResolver
        Conflict.ConflictType.ARMOR_CONFLICT    | TestArmorResolver

    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `isCase` like so:

```
class BattleResolverFactoryTest extends Specification {

    def uut = new BattleResolverFactory()

    @Unroll
    def "should return proper BattleResolver for given ConflictType"(Conflict.ConflictType conflictType, Class<? extends BattleResolver> expectedInstance) {
        when:
        def battleResolver = BattleResolverFactory.getResolver(conflictType)

        then:
        expectedClass.isCase(battleResolver)

        where:
        conflictType                            | expectedClass
        Conflict.ConflictType.INFANTRY_CONFLICT | TestInfantryResolver
        Conflict.ConflictType.ARMOR_CONFLICT    | TestArmorResolver

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

As tim_yates said you can use the groovy function `isCase` or the java function `isAssignableFrom`, or you could use the groovy `in` keyword (which delegates to `isCase`).

- `expectedClass.isCase(battleResolver)`
- `expectedClass.isAssignableFrom(battleResolver)`
- `expectedClass in battleResolver`

Comment: in the case of the `in` keyword, the usage would be reversed. It would actually be `battleResolver in expectedClass`